# dropdown-menu occupies new space instead of relative position

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am using [bootstrap dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/) in navBar on menu(three dots) icon
[image]

but problem is in mobile device when I open navBar and click on menu button then menu dropdown shows up but it takes space instead of showing on top of content. As shown in picture

[image]

here is the html code

```html
<div class="dropdown" style="display: inline-block">
    <img src="{{environment.assets_base_url}}assets/images/menu.png" id="menuid" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="menuid">
        <a *ngIf="environment.enable_settigs" class="dropdown-item" href="{{settings_link}}">Settings</a>
        <!--<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{upgrade_link}}">Payment</a>-->
        <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="myLogout()">Logout</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please create working fiddle, So we can trying to fixed your issue.

Comment: Please post the entire Navbar code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: absolute;` and set it's top and left relative to parent div for `dropdown-menu`. Also, add `z-index` to display it on the top of other elements (it sets the stack order).

By setting `position: absolute;` your `dropdown-menu` container position is set relative to its closest positioned ancestor. Make sure you it's parent div which is `dropdown` position is `relative` (not set to static).

Comment: I did try `position: absolute;` but how can I get parent div location and set menu's top and left accordingly?

Comment: @ZohabAli set the `dropdown` position relative and then the position of menu is relative to it. You do not need to find the location of dropdown icon or parent div.

Comment: Its not taking space, but there is slight problem I am having. Its showing menu towards left as you can see (https://prnt.sc/n5vads). Any suggestions about showing it towards right? Although I am already using `dropdown-menu-right`

Comment: @ZohabAli play with left and right properties for `dropdown-menu`. Set the `right: 0` first and see, if does not work `left: 50px'. 50px is just an example, but set it the value which works for you.

Comment: I had to add `position: relative;` to parent and `position:absolute; left:0;` to child and it solved my problem. Thanks